# How to use onclick on a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

i have one paragraph and one button inside a div tag. I want to use onlick="" method on div tag but not on the button which is inside that div tag. How can I do this.

```html
<div class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample{{data.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <p>
    <strong>{{ data.name }} / {{ data.messager_profile }}</strong> <span>{{ data.message_headline }}</span>
    <br>
    <span style="float: left;">8 days ago</span>
  </p>

  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  <br>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample{{data.id}}">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <strong>Detailed Message:-</strong> <span>{{ data.message }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your question answered? If not, please comment accordingly. If yes, please pick an answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) method. This will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent container. Here is an example using your HTML. I used jQuery since Bootstrap is involved.

```js
$(".alert.alert-secondary").click(function() {
  console.log("Parent container");
})

$(".btn-close").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("Button");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample{{data.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">

  <p>
    <strong>{{ data.name }} / {{ data.messager_profile }}</strong> <span>{{ data.message_headline }}</span>
    <br>
    <span style="float: left;">8 days ago</span>
  </p>


  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">button</button>
  <br>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample{{data.id}}">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <strong>Detailed Message:-</strong> <span>{{ data.message }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is neither need for jQuery here, nor for changing the behaviour of the button click. Instead, inside your click handler, check for the element clicked:

```js
document
  .querySelector('.alert.alert-secondary') // select the div
  .addEventListener('click', function(e) { // register a click listener
    const clickedElement = e.target; // the event object holds information about the clicked element
    if (clickedElement.tagName !== 'BUTTON') { // make sure you don't react to button clicks bubbling to the div
      console.log('div clicked');
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample{{data.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  <p>
    <strong>{{ data.name }} / {{ data.messager_profile }}</strong> <span>{{ data.message_headline }}</span>
    <br>
    <span style="float: left;">8 days ago</span>
  </p>

  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">x</button>
  <br>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample{{data.id}}">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <strong>Detailed Message:-</strong> <span>{{ data.message }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```